# Scroll to clicked element using Isotope2 and Scroll-js

Tags: javascript, scroll, jquery-isotope

I am using [Isotope2](https://isotope.metafizzy.co/v2/) and [Scroll-JS](https://github.com/mkay581/scroll-js) on a project. There's a number of grid items in a Masonry layout. When a user clicks on a grid item it expands to full width and I want this item to scroll to the top of the viewport. My problem is that instead of scrolling from the current position within the page, the scroll starts from the top of the page. I've made a [simplified case study in Codepen](https://codepen.io/crs1138/pen/mLGmqp). I would prefer to stick to Vanilla Javascript rather than using jQuery.

Here's my Javascript so far…

```
window._ = (...myvar) => console.log(...myvar);
const Services = {
  /**
   * default values for Isotope
   * @type {Object}
   */
  gridDefaults: {
    itemSelector: '.grid-item',
    percentPositions: true,
    masonry: {
      gutter: '.gutter-sizer',
      columnWidth: '.grid-sizer'
    }
  },

  clickedItem: null,

  /**
   * Initializes the module
   * @return {undefined} Executive method used to plug the module in.
   */
  init: () => {
    _('Services module initialized');
    Services.scroll = new Scroll(document.body);
    const grid = document.querySelector('.grid');
    const gridItems = grid.querySelectorAll('.grid-item');
    gridItems.forEach( gridItem => {
      gridItem.addEventListener('click', Services.Listeners.toggleExpand);
    });

  // call the Isotope function to process the grid element
    const iso = Services.iso = new Isotope( grid, Services.gridDefaults );
    iso.on('layoutComplete', Services.Listeners.scroll);
  },
  Listeners: {
    toggleExpand: function(e){
      const clickedGridItem = Services.clickedGridItem = Services.Helpers.clickedGridItem(e);
      clickedGridItem.classList.toggle('grid-item--width2');
      Services.iso.layout();
    },
    scroll: function(e) {
      _(Services.clickedGridItem);
      const scroll = Services.scroll;
      scroll.toElement(Services.clickedGridItem, {duration: 1000});
    }
  },
  Helpers: {
    clickedGridItem: function( eve ) {
      _(eve.path);
      return clickedItem = eve.path.find( (el) => 
        el.classList.contains('grid-item') );
    }
  }
};

Services.init();
```

This is what the Scroll-JS documentation recommends for scrolling to an element (and it works fine in a test)

```
var myElement = document.body.getElementsByClassName('my-element')[0];
var scroll = new Scroll(document.body);
scroll
  .toElement(myElement)
  .then(function () {
    // done scrolling to the element
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the answer from the **scroll-js** developer.

> @crs1138 there seems to be a problem with your example. all of the grid-items are absolutely positioned and the parent element ( in your example) has no overflow content. Per README, [your parent element needs to always have overflow content](https://github.com/mkay581/scroll-js#scrolling-an-element).
>
> In addition to that, I suspect there is something being done to the elements in the other JS files that is causing your page to redraw back to 0 in height.